# How to automatically update ForeignKeys to have ", on_delete=models.PROTECT"

Tags: django

I'm updating old code to the latest Django version.
The ForeignKeys need ", `on_delete=models.PROTECT`".
There are almost a hundred of them. How do I automatically add ", on_delete=models.PROTECT" to each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to use a regular expression here. Given the `ForeignKey`s are defined on a single line, and you did not define something else with `ForeignKey`, you could try to edit this inline, for example with [**`sed`** [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed):

```
sed -i -E 's/(ForeignKey\s*\(.*)\)\s*$/\1, on_delete=models.PROTECT)/' */models.py
```

We here will thus do an inline replacement of all the `models.py` in a directory, where we replace `ForeignKey(…)` with `ForeignKey(…, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.

Perhaps not all `ForeignKey`s can be replaced, but you can slightly alter the regular expression to accept different patterns.

Note that you probably will need to update [**`OneToOneField`** fields [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) as well.