# How to set on_delete=models.CASCADE default in python 3?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

Currently I am working to **convert my python2 Django web-project into python 3**.

My project contains lots of models.py files so I have to add manually `on_delete=models.CASCADE` in all files where I have set default it in python 2.

Now there are around more than 2000 instances where I need to do same practice.

Is there are any hacks or possible solution available so that I can set `on_delete=models.CASCADE` in my all models instantly.

Comment: You could subclass the `ForeignKey` and pass that as default, but that is likely not a good idea either. I propose you use a tool like `sed` to do an automatic replace.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57913144/67579

Comment: Use regular expression I have thought but still any other solution available without regex.